# Is there a good ClojureScript workflow?

Tags: clojure, workflow, read-eval-print-loop, clojurescript

I'm trying to use ClojureScript for a project. To be a happy developer, I need a quick feedback-loop: write some code and see it as soon as it's possible. I'd also love to use REPL in the context of the current page.

I'm using `lein-cljsbuild` and from the issues I'm having I think I failed to set it up properly.

First of all, compilation time for a small file is too big, even after "JWM warm-up" with `:optimizations :simple`:

```
Compiling "resources/public/js/cljs.js" from ["src-cljs"]...
Successfully compiled "resources/public/js/cljs.js" in 8.233018 seconds.
Compiling "resources/public/js/cljs.js" from ["src-cljs"]...
Successfully compiled "resources/public/js/cljs.js" in 5.522989 seconds.
Compiling "resources/public/js/cljs.js" from ["src-cljs"]...
Successfully compiled "resources/public/js/cljs.js" in 8.144354 seconds.
```

Second, from time to time I get stuff like this:

```
Compiling "resources/public/js/cljs.js" from ["src-cljs"]...
Compiling "resources/public/js/cljs.js" failed.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.regex.Matcher.getTextLength(Matcher.java:1140)
at java.util.regex.Matcher.reset(Matcher.java:291)
at java.util.regex.Matcher.<init>(Matcher.java:211)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(Pattern.java:888)
at clj_stacktrace.utils$re_gsub.invoke(utils.clj:6)

# ... many similar useless lines

at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:532)
at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
```

These stacktraces (most of the time related to syntax errors, as I understood from experimenting), are worse than not helpful: not only they provide zero clues about the error, they also stop automatic recompilation. After every such stacktrace I should do these things:

- Figure out what's the problem, using a technique I call "pretend you're a parser". Thank God it's Lisp and the only thing I should do is to carefully count matching parentheses.
- Press `Cmd-C` in the shell where the `lein cljsbuild auto` runs
- Run `lein cljsbuild auto` again
- Make some useless change, like inserting a newline, in the file, to trigger a new build
- Wait for ~30 seconds until the file is compiled again, since the JVM has to "warm-up" again
- In many cases at this point I get another stacktrace, after getting which I have to lather, rinse and repeat all the damned procedure

Third thing which I failed to understand is REPL. From the interwebs I've learned how to connect `rlwrap lein trampoline cljsbuild repl-listen` to the current page. However, every reload, navigation, and syntax error (god forbid you forget to use `rlwrap` and press an arrow key) in the console makes the REPL completely stuck. I have to restart it (~10 seconds) and reload the page after that, then start again trying stuff out in a friendly environment.

I think, probably someone has figured it all out and has a workflow that works. Please help me set it all up from the start, because I feel like a failed software engineer.

Comment: Hi Valya, have my response helped you with the clojure workflow? I think this workflow is very confortable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [figwheel](https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel)! It's like livereload on steroids.
Working with clojurescript and front-end development was never so much fun!
[See for yourself](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KZjFVdU8VLI) (the demo is a bit outdated – it's even better now!)
It not just reloads the page when files are changed – it provides you interactive programming [Bret Victor was talking about](https://vimeo.com/36579366) (I recommend you to watch that talk if you haven't)

Answer (score 5):

For me [Catnip](https://github.com/bodil/catnip) provides the best dev experience for ClojureScript at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried inside Emacs this tool https://github.com/cemerick/austin and works very well as you can see in his demo and screencast.

Have a good development
Juan

Answer (score 2):

When in development mode turn **:optimizations** to **:none**, it makes a huge difference it won't change the initial compile time but any additional changes will only take milliseconds typically.

I have the following in my project.clj

```
 :cljsbuild {:builds [{;; Directories of interest:
                        :source-paths ["src"]
                        ;; Compiler flags:
                        :compiler {;; Where to save the file:
                                   :output-to "resources/public/js/app.js"
                                   ;; Where to put the output directory
                                   :output-dir "resources/public/js/out"
                                   ;; Optimizations:
                                   :optimizations :none
                                   }}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

> compilation time for a small file is too big

Try `:optimizations :whitespace`. And use `lein cljsbuild auto`

> Second, from time to time I get stuff like this: ......

I haven't met this problem before. It looks like a bug in cljsbuild. Try to change another version maybe. I'm using `[lein-cljsbuild "1.0.2"]` with `[org.clojure/clojurescript "0.0-2156"]`. The `1.0.3` doesn't work in my setup.

> Third thing which I failed to understand is REPL

In your case the key point is to find a way reloading namespaces **without restart REPL or reloading page**.

I find `load-file` is good for this.

My workflow is:

1. First start REPL: `rlwrap lein trampoline cljsbuild repl-listen`
2. Make sure there is `(repl/connect "http://localhost:9000/repl")` in my code.
3. Open my page in browser.
4. Do some test `(my-namespace/my-func a b c)`
5. Edit my codes.
6. In my REPL, run `(load-file "path-to-my-file.cljs")`
7. **Repeat `4`**

This is still a pretty annoying workflow. `load-file` is slow and fragile so sometimes I  browser to test. I hope someone can provide a better answer.